# How to calculate a mean of measurements taken at the same time (n-hours window) on different days in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a dataset with measurements acquired almost every 2-hours over a week. I would like to calculate a mean of measurements taken at the same time on different days. For example, I want to calculate the mean of every measurement taken between 12:00 and 13:59.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#generating test dataframe
date_today = datetime.now()
time_of_taken_measurment = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + 
timedelta(72), freq='2H20MIN')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, 
size=len(time_of_taken_measurment))
df = pd.DataFrame({'measurementTimestamp': time_of_taken_measurment, 'measurment': data})
df = df.set_index('measurementTimestamp')

#Calculating the mean for measurments taken in the same hour
hourly_average = df.groupby([df.index.hour]).mean() 
hourly_average
```

The code above gives me this output:

```
0   47.967742
1   43.354839
2   46.935484
  .....
22  42.833333
23  52.741935
```

I would like to have a result like this:

```
0   mean0
2   mean1
4   mean2
  .....
20  mean10
22  mean11
```

I was trying to solve my problem using [rolling_mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html) function, but I could not find a way to apply it to my static case.

Comment: Something like `df.rolling(2).mean()[::2]`?.  Can you show your attempt with `rolling_mean` and what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in `floor` functionality of datetimeIndex, which allows you to easily create 2 hour time bins.

```
df.groupby(df.index.floor('2H').time).mean()
```

Output:

```
          measurment
00:00:00   51.516129
02:00:00   54.868852
04:00:00   52.935484
06:00:00   43.177419
08:00:00   43.903226
10:00:00   55.048387
12:00:00   50.639344
14:00:00   48.870968
16:00:00   43.967742
18:00:00   49.225806
20:00:00   43.774194
22:00:00   50.590164
```